# nuxtjs and ssr with flickity slider and more plugins

Tags: javascript, import, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, flickity

I transform my current website to a nuxtjs and vuejs page. With nuxt, i want to do server-side-rendering. So in the end a static html page. There were problems with the import statements in my vue components. So now i will optimize my imports for the ssr. My current solution looks like this:

```
    let Flickity = {};
if (process.browser) {
    Flickity = require('flickity');
}
```

In one component, i use the flickity slider and moreover the plugins flickity-sync and flickity-fade. Normally i would just add import states lie this:

```
let Flickity = {};
if (process.browser) {
    Flickity = require('flickity');
}

import 'flickity-sync';
import 'flickity-fade';
import 'flickity-as-nav-for';
```

But this don´t work with the ssr (server-side-rendering). I thought i could requre all and merge the objects, but this do not work either.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is easy:

```
let Flickity = {};
if (process.browser) {
    Flickity = require('flickity');
    require('flickity-sync');
    require('flickity-fade');
    require('flickity-as-nav-for')
}
```

:D